# How should I sort 100 Billion items in OCaml using only immutable things?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

ok, let's say we have `100 billion` items that need to be sorted.

Our memory is big enough for these items.

Can we still use List.sort (Merge sort) to sort them?

My concerns have two parts:

1. Will the extra spaces that `mergesort` need become a concern in this case?
2. Since we use immutable data structures, we have to repeatedly create new lists for the `100 billion` items during sorting, will this become an disadvantage? in terms of performance?

For sorting `100 billion` items, should I use `array` in this case?

Comment: “Our memory is big enough for these items.” You have a computer with 800 gigabytes of memory?

Comment: @PascalCuoq: reportedly folks at MPI have terabyte-memory computers.

Comment: Couldn't you split that data in 2 halves, sort them separatly, and merge the results? (Just kiddin' ...)

Comment: @PascalCuoq well consider this question as existing in `Alice's Wonderland`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [standard mergesort implementation](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/list.ml#L227) is clever in not reallocating too much memory (the split-in-half at the beginning allocates no new memory). Given an input list of `n` conses, it will allocate `n * log(n)` list conses in the worst case (with an essentially identical best case). Given that the values of the elements themselves will be shared between the input, intermediary and output lists, you will only allocate 3 words by list cons, which means that the sort will allocate `3 * n * log(n)` words in memory in total (for `n = 100 billion`, `3 * log(n)` is `110`, which is quite a huge constant factor).

On the other hand, garbage collection can collect some of that memory: the worst-case memory usage is total *live* memory, not total allocated memory. In fact, the intermediary lists built during the `log(n)` layers of recursive subcalls can be collected before any result is returned (they become dead at the same rate the final `merge` allocates new cells), so this algorithm keeps `n` additional live cons cells in the worst case, which means only `3*n` words or `24*n` bytes. For `n = 100 billion`, that means 2.4 additional terabytes of memory, just as much as you needed to store the spine of the input list in the first place.

Finally, if you keep no reference to the input list itself, you can collect the first half of it as soon as it is sorted, giving you a `n/2` worst-case bound instead of `n`. And you can collect the first half of this first half while you sort the first half, giving you a `n/4` worst-case bound instead of `n/2`. Going to the limit with this reasoning, I believe that with enough GC work, you can in fact sort the list entirely in place -- modulo some constant-size memory pool for a stop&copy first generation GC, whose size will impact the *time* performance of the algorithm.

Comment: “if you keep no reference to the input list itself” This would require special care in the way `mergesort` is written. By default, if the function is written `let rec mergesort l = …`, `l` is alive until the call has returned, even if `mergesort` stops referring to `l` halfway through. Function `mergesort` would need for instance to take a ref to a list and set that ref to contain `[]` when it is done with the list. Such a trick would allow the original list to be recovered at the end of the next cycle.

Comment: The above because `mergesort` is not tail-recursive. Tail-calls erase the arguments from the stack, and thus allow them to be recovered.

Comment: I checked for this problem when writing my message. The `merge` function is always called in tail position, so I think it is correct that the memory corresponding to the sublayers will be freed before the list is returned (at the same rate `merge` allocates new cell). Now that you insist on it, I don't think the current implementation allows to collect the first half of `l` for this reason, so maybe the last part of my message does not stand. I'll ask Damien and maybe propose a patch.